# Best open source software load balancer for Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, load-balancing

I have a service that listens on a socket and handle requests arriving to it and a client loading this service. I want to setup more nodes of the service and use a load balancer to balance the workload.

What is , in your opinion and experience, the best open source software load balancer for Linux?

Thanks,
Ronen,

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at Pound?

http://www.apsis.ch/pound/

Answer (score 2):

At www.loadbalancer.org we use Pound for SSL termination , LVS (IPVS) for Layer 4 load balancing and HAproxy for Layer 7 load balancing. But these solutions balance TCP and UDP traffic, are you after a local socket based solution?

Answer (score 1):

how about  [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) which is a open source proxy server which can do the load balancing

Answer (score 0):

There is [malabarista](http://github.com/brunodecarvalho/malabarista) by [Bruno de Carvalho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366091/brunodecarvalho)

Comment: That thing is little more than a Netty advanced tutorial :P Take a look at http://www.inlab.de/balance.html